# can user's input in an html form produce a python list without javascript

Tags: html, list, python-2.7, user-input

I want the user's input to eventually be modeled with a db.stringListProperty(). What would the input format have to look like and how would the user's inputs have to be constructed (with []'s, with quotes, with commas, etc.), if this is possible? I am using jinja2 for form templates, if that matters. (Extra credit for how to validate that the data was input correctly .)
Thanks.

I get this error from appengine.

```
raise BadValueError('Property %s must be a list' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property choices must be a list
```

The error occurs on this line below.

person.choices = self.request.get('choices')

```
class PQ(db.Model):
    choices = db.StringListProperty()


    key = db.Key.from_path("PQ", ID_id)
    person = PQ.get(key)
    template_values = {'ID_id':person.key(),
                      'p': person,
                      }
    path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'add_person.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))


class AddPerson(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        ID_id = self.request.get('ID')
        key = db.Key.from_path("PQ", ID_id)
        person = PQ.get(key)

        person.choices = self.request.get('choices')
        person.put()
        self.redirect("/?ID=%s" % ID_id)



add_person.html
<html>
  <body>

<div id="inputdata">
    <form action="add_person" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Enter your list of choices. Your list must follow this format:
            ["Less","Same","More"] </label>
    <input type="textbox" name="choices" size="30" value="{{ p.choices }}"></input><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a place to come to get people to write code for you. It's a place to ask for assistance with code that you've written.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to include my code and error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you get this error because `choices` must be a list type, but the value that you get from your request is a string - and it'll always be, since you get it from your HTTP request.

On the form side, it doesn't matter what format the user types data in, since it's always passed as a string - a comma-separated list should suffice. Then you could parse it with e.g. `self.request.get('choices').split(",")` (and trim whitespace on your side so you don't bother the user with exact whitespace requirements).

Best practices dictate that you should assist the user as much as possible - if you have a set of pre-defined choices, you could use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) or a similar widget to guide the user with making their selection.

Comment: Using .split(",") is almost a perfect answer for me if I give my users  the format to follow: ['Less','Same','More']. But the echoing output looks like this: [u'Less',u'Same',u'More']. Is there some jinja2 or python function that can return the output so it looks like ['Less','Same','More'] ? Or even better, is there a way to use space in split and return the perceived result to be a space delimited string? TIA

Comment: `[u'Less',u'Same',u'More']` just means that you're getting unicode strings (which is Python's default behavior, as far as I recall). What's your problem with that? Anyway, you shouldn't have any problems using a space in `split()`.

Comment: My problem is solved by using your .split idea, splitting with a space: self.request.get('choices').split(), where choices here is a temporary variable on the html form. And then joining the list person.choices with a space to produce the html result: choices = ' '.join(person.choices) . Users supply their list space-delimited, for example: Less Same More. Thanks very much.